# Windows - Check if the monitor is powered on or off (check with software)

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management, teamviewer, device-manager

So I turn off my monitor (it's connected using a VGA cable and I turn it off with its power button) and I connect to my PC (Windows 10) from another device, mostly using AnyDesk, but TeamViewer is also available. The monitor is from LG Flatron models.

**I want to make sure that nobody turned the monitor on again. How can I check that from this device (the device that is connected to my PC, I mean I don't want to go near my PC, so I should do this by software)?**

Note: I'm a developer, so I can do it programmatically (probably).

Comment: incidentally there's a [*nix question here concerning HDMI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61857/detect-if-hdmi-monitor-is-switched-off) that may be of interest - suggesting that it's possible in linux, so it may be [possible under windows too](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ee7bd485-2312-4b57-a82a-3008491970e3/how-to-detect-monitor-power-state?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues). You don't state what cable the monitor is connected with on your system though.

Comment: @smock I added the cable type.

Comment: Ugh, you might be out of luck then. Can you just unplug the cable instead of turning the monitor off? (if it's that important to remain off)

Comment: Yeah unplugging and setting black screen (using AnyDesk and TeamViewer) are both good ideas. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind, that if you unplug the screen, windows has no information to draw resolution from, so you will get an 800x600 resolution when you connect without any option to change it, until you connect the monitor again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the computer is connected through display port or DVI-D, windows will install and uninstall the monitor as a plug and play device. If your monitor is connected through these cables, you can check in the device manager if your monitor is listed (installed) in order to figure out if the monitor is turned on or off.

If your monitor is connected through HDMI or SUB-D (vga), windows will always list these devices as connected even if they are turned off.

That said, Both AnyDesk and TeamViewer have an option to blank the remote screen when you connect. If you really want to ensure that no one can see the screen while you are connected, connect, then blank the remote screen. The only real issue here is that if someone sits behind your pc and they see a blank screen, they may think its turned off or crashed and may restart your pc unknowingly.

Comment: It's connected using VGA. The blank screen was a good idea, so I'll use that. Thanks very much!